# "FacetSearchException: no bean named 'myBean' is defined" accessing CS in BackOffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I run into the following exception when trying to access the customer support section in the Hybris backoffice (https://localhost:9002/backoffice), after login:

```
de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.FacetSearchException: No bean named 'myBean' is defined
```

... Caused by:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myBean' is defined
```

This bean does not appear anywhere in my project. One of my coworkers suggested it could be referenced in one of the Solr specific database tables, but was unable to provide further explanation.

The administration section of the BO works fine, this error is specific to the customer support section.

I tried a system update on Solr-related extensions (solrfacetsearchbackoffice, solrserver, solrfacetsearch, solrfacetsearchhmc), ran a full SOLR indexation, and cleared the cache, but it didn't help.

Could I get some clarification on how the solr indexing works on the database level, and what the possible causes of this error could be?

(Hybris version: 6.4.0.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, I managed to figure it out. There were two distinct problems:

1. "No bean named 'myBean' is defined": the bean was a provider which was referenced to by indexed types. By going in HMC > System > Facet search > Indexed types, I found a property which had the same name as the bean and deleted it. This allowed me to redo a full indexation and the error disappeared from the logs. However, this did not resolve the second issue, which is as follows...
2. Customer support not appearing: this was an issue related to the groups associated to the logged in user (admin in my case). By adding the right group to the user (under HMC > User > Employees) I made the customer support section work again.

Hope this helps someone in the future!